# Difference in Stripe Source Endpoints in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

What is the difference between the following methods of creating a source via stripe:
`\Stripe\Customer::createSource`
and
`$stripe->customers->createSource`.  Only the former works for me, but all I see is the latter in the Stripe API docs.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
\Stripe\Customer::createSource
```

This is a basically a dynamic factory method like much of Laravel framework. It will initialize a new stripe customer object for you and then call createSouce method on it.

This should work if you configure your [global api key like...](https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication?lang=php)

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc");

\Stripe\Source::create([
  "type" => "ach_credit_transfer",
  "currency" => "usd",
  "owner" => [
    "email" => "jenny.rosen@example.com"
  ]
]);
```

[Create Source Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/create)

Comment: I do have it configured that way and it does work. I’m more curious as to why the stripe api docs point to using $stripe->customers->createSource then. What’s the difference?

Comment: the create method is one of the static factory methods for Source, this is not the case for Customer createSource. Looks like customer(s) is a collection not a model.